# I got this AC universal adapter for my laptop how to use it?

Tags: ac-adapter

On the universal AC adapter there is the switch 15, 16 or 19.5 volt. I read the manual to set the switch to what it say on the back of the laptop. It say output= 19 Volt on the label back on my laptop, should I select the universal adapter switch 16volt? Will 19.5 volt destroy the laptop??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

19.5 volts should work fine and will not destroy your laptop (19 and 19.5 volts are close enough to each other). 16 volts will work but charge the battery more slowly. Use the matched 19 volts. Make sure the polarity of the universal charger matches. The back of the laptop or its documentation will tell you that. The charger may say it is approved for your laptop.

Comment: I update my Q with image of adapter and pc

Comment: I cannot see real well in the photos. Likely it is center positive and outside ground (negative).

Comment: The adapter website say the adapter works with my laptop so I it's should be ok I think
https://www.trust.com/en/product/19138-primo-90w-universal-laptop-charger

Comment: Yes you should be fine with the adapter.